# Angular - html rendering issue

Tags: angularjs

I have injection problem. I have no idea why my html is not rendering.

Render HTML in the view; it should be processed/created in the controller, and then rendered in the html view.

This code is currently not working as the html appears as text:

```js
var myApp = angular.module('myApp', []);


myApp.controller('MyCtrl', myController);
      
myController.$inject = ['$scope']
   function myController($scope) {

       $scope.html = "<b>HTML inserted</b>";
};
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.5.7/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-controller="MyCtrl as vm">
    <div>Html</div>
    <div>{{html}}</div>

<br/>
</div>
```

Comment: add ngSantize - https://jsfiddle.net/6a6726Lm/5/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For rendering of html in angular try the ng-bind-html attribute.

In your case:

```
<div ng-bind-html="html"></div>
```

More info:

[ngBindHtml in AngularJS](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngBindHtml)

Edit: Also add ngSanitize dependence: 
[ngSanitize](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngSanitize)

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/52gfmff1/1/ Hmmm. does not seems working.. what's wrong with my code?

Comment: On ng-controller="MyCtrl as vm" call to the properties of controller with vm.html.
ng-bind-html="vm.html".
Also, the inner of div has to be empty because the content is replaced by ng-bind-html.

Comment: Sorry - Ive got everything you said. still not appearing. Can you please have a look last time?

https://jsfiddle.net/6a6726Lm/1/

Comment: Sorry, I was wrong in my last commet. Use my first comment and add 'ngSanitize' as people says.

Answer (score 0):

try adding 'ngSanitize' in your module dependencies if you're using ng-bind-html